# How to periodically save tensorflow model using saved_model API?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So for various reasons (such as its language-independence) I want to use tensorflow's [saved_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#apis_to_build_and_load_a_savedmodel) API for saving/loading models.  I can save everything (and restore it successfully) with a call to `builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables()` at the end of training, but I don't see any way to save periodically.  Tensorflow docs on this are very sparse, and the template code they provide ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder)) doesn't help me:

```
...
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                  ["foo-tag"],
                                  signature_def_map=foo_signatures,
                                  assets_collection=foo_assets)
...

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph(["bar-tag", "baz-tag"])
...

builder.save()
```

Calling `builder.save()` does not save the new variables into the model.  It just updates the model protobuf.

What am I missing?  How do I save after e.g. the nth epoch using `saved_model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after looking through the tensorflow code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py) and elsewhere, it looks like the answer is "you can't".  `SavedModelBuilder` is really just designed for models outside of the training phase, and it allows you to add metagraphs and choose which sets of variables to load/save (i.e. TRAINING vs. SERVING) but that's it.  `SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph_and_variables`, for example, can be called exactly once, and there is no `SavedModelBuilder.update_variables` or anything like that.  While training, on the other hand, you need to use the `Saver` class and save checkpoints and those associated files.  Why there isn't a unified system for this I have no idea but apparently that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are saved when you call `builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables()`, because `saver.save()` is called inside it. [See here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py#L421)

Solution:

Just call `saver.save(sess, export_dir+'/variables/variables', write_meta_graph=False, write_state=False)` before `builder.save()`.